# Create server TCP in Winodws Univeral App (Javascript) and client Android

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

I want create a tcp server in c# and use it in universal app javascript based project, and I create the folowing code (Server):

```
//C# Windows Runtime Component

public sealed class Server
    {
        public Server()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Server...");
        }

        public async void Connection()
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.10");
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ip, portNumber);
            TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);

            try
            {
                server.Start();
                Debug.WriteLine("Server started ... " + ip.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            while (true)
            {
                client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                byte[] recievedBuffer = new byte[100];
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                stream.Read(recievedBuffer, 0, recievedBuffer.Length);
                string msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recievedBuffer, 0, recievedBuffer.Length);
                Debug.WriteLine(msg);
            }
        }
    }


//in HTML
<script>
    console.log("test");
    var server = new Server.Server();
    server.connection();
    console.log("msg");
</script>
```

I don't know why Debug.WriteLine and console.log method don't work, nothing are printed in output or in javascript console.

The Server code works with Android client, if the server is "Console App" project but in "Universal App Javscript" nothing append, I don't have warning or error. 
So I don't know if I'm doing bad, because console.log and Debug.WriteLine don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that work with windows universal app, I remove Connection and add followings methods:

```
public async void StartServer()
{
            try
            {
                var streamSocketListener = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener();
                streamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived += this.StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived;
                await streamSocketListener.BindEndpointAsync(new HostName("192.168.0.10"), PortNumber);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){}
}

private async void StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
            string request;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
            {
                request = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
            }
            sender.Dispose();
}


//in main.js just call this method
new Server.Server().startServer();
```

But I still don't know why Debug.WriteLine() in c# and console.log() in javascript don't work.

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine()` works in debug mode, the javascript UWP doesn't support inline js code. You need to write it in back-end js file.